# Okta signout don't work in Angular Applicaiton

Tags: okta, okta-api

I am using OKTA SDK for the angular following [enter link description here](https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/sign-into-spa/angular/before-you-begin/)

this documentation. I am also using OktaCallbackComponent and OktaAuthService for authentication.
I can log in successfully. after a successful login OKTA redirects me to  OktaCallbackComponent where they store some keys in localstroge and finally, I get navigated to my main page.

now when I click on the logout button from the application it does not work. As I see it the page loads and immediately navigates to the callback component and again navigates to the main page. whereas I want the login page should come to the user.

this is my logout function.

```
  async logout(){
   this.oktaAuth.tokenManager.clear()
   await this.oktaAuth.signOut();
   this.router.navigate(['/login']);
   this.toastr.success('Logout Successfully', 'See you next time' , {timeOut: 5000});
  }
```

can anyone help me with what could be the issue.

```
  {
    path: 'main',
    component: OpDataTableComponent,
    canActivate: [ OktaAuthGuard ],
    data: {
      title: 'Main Page'
    }
  },


 {
    path: CALLBACK_PATH,
    component: OktaCallbackComponent,
    // Later: Add a component
  },

  {
    path: 'login',
    // component: LoginComponent,
    component:OktaLoginComponent,
    canActivate: [checkAfterLoginService],
    
    data: {
      title: 'Login Page'
    }
  }
```

CheckAfterLoginService

```
export class checkAfterLoginService {
  constructor(private oktaAuth: OktaAuthService,private tokenService: TokenService, private router: Router) { }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean | Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> {
    if(this.oktaAuth.isAuthenticated())
    {
      return this.router.navigateByUrl('/main');
    }else
    {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Okta configuration.

```
const ISSUER = 'https://...../oauth2/default';
const HOST = window.location.host;
const REDIRECT_URI = 'https://..../callback';
const SCOPES = 'openid profile email';

const config = {
  issuer: ISSUER,
  clientId: '.....',
  redirectUri: REDIRECT_URI,
  scopes: SCOPES.split(/\s+/)
};
```

P.s logout URL added to the application setting is https://../login route.
how can I solve the issue or what could be the issue? your help is much appreciated.

Comment: I am not logged in in any other tabs or in okta organization account.

Comment: Do you see a CORS error in your browser console? You might need to add `http://localhost:4200` as a trusted origin on Okta.

Comment: @MattRaible , Hi No, I don't see any CORS error in my console.

Comment: @MattRaible I am experiencing two different behaviors , explaining those in below comments.

Comment: @MattRaible In the first step, I am logging to www.mywebsite.com (app registered to my out organization)
now, on the second step, I enter www. ABC-oktapreview. On the other tab, it doesn't ask me for the authentication process. Instead, it redirects me to the www.abc-oktapreview.com/app/UserHome page. And at last, when I log out from www.abc-oktapreviw.com/app/UserHome, this process goes successfully, and now when I try to logout from www.mywebsite.com, it works, at short for a successful log out I must log out from my okta-organization first and from my application at last.

Comment: @MattRaible in another case, first I am logging to www.abc-oktapreview.com. On the other tab, I enter www.mywebsite.com, the www.mywebsite.com does not ask me for authentication and redirects me to the main page, now I am logging out from www.abc-oktapreview.com I expect entering www.mywebsite.com should automatically bring the authentication login page since I logged out from www.abc-oktapreview.com but still without any issue I can go to the main page of www.mywebiste.com although okta-auth-guard protects it. I can log in to my app even after closing the browser without any authentication.

Comment: @MattRaible could you please help me with what can be the issue and how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your `logout()` method to be as follows:

```
async logout(){
  await this.oktaAuth.signOut();
  this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  this.toastr.success('Logout Successfully', 'See you next time' , {timeOut: 5000});
}
```

You're currently clearing the tokens manually, which makes our underlying Auth JS SDK thinking you've already logged out. `this.oktaAuth.signOut()` should clean up the tokens for you. If you still want to clear them manually, make sure and do it after `signOut()`.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues, but I wanted to redirect back to the okta login screen. This is what worked for my situation.

```
public logout(): void {
    const oktaBaseUrl: string = `${environment.okta.issuer}/v1`;
    const oktaTokenStorage: any = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('okta-token-storage'));
    const oktaIdToken = oktaTokenStorage?.idToken;

    this.oktaAuth.logout();
    window.location.href = `${oktaBaseUrl}/logout?id_token_hint=${oktaIdToken.idToken}&post_logout_redirect_uri=${environment.okta.postLogoutRedirectUri}`;
}
```